# How to set a maximum popup window height for auto completion?

Tags: autocompletion

As title, when there're tens of suggestions, the popup can expand the entire window. How to set a maximum window height for auto completion popup? I'd like to have a scrolling window.

Comment: Isnt there something like pumwinheight or pumheight? I cant remember off the top of my head though

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes pumheight is what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an option called `'pumheight'`. Thanks @D.BenKnoble!